# What is the cause of the "502 Bad Gateway" after Ghost 1.8.7 update

Tags: nginx, ghost-blog, ghost

I recently installed Ghost 1.8.4 and Nginx on my *AWS ec2 Ubuntu 16.04* server. When I loaded my blog site, it correctly took me to the Ghost home page, from where I logged into Ghost admin. On the admin screen, there was a message to update.

I ran `ghost update` in putty

The update appeared to be successful, but when I returned to my blog site, I received the following error:

> 502 Bad Gateway
>   nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)

1. Does anyone know a probably cause of this error and how to resolve?
2. I checked some posts, which suggested I should have turned Ghost off before the update. If this is true, is my ghost installation now corrupted?
3. I went to my ghost directory in `/var/www/ghost` and tried to run:

   `sudo service ghost start`

   but it returned:

   `Failed to start ghost.service: Unit ghost.service not found`

   and trying to stop, returns `Unit ghost.service not loaded`. Am I running the command from the correct location?

Comment: any output for `which ghost`?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Ghost CMS https://ghost.org/ installed via CLI

Comment: No, I mean executing the command from terminal `which ghost` and `ghost start` what does that give you?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, `which ghost` returns `/usr/bin/ghost` and when i go to `var/www/ghost` and run `ghost start` i get: `✖ Starting Ghost
An error occurred.
Message: 'EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/ghost/.ghost-cli''


Debug Information:
    Node Version: v6.11.3
    Ghost-CLI Version: 1.1.1
    Environment: production
    Command: 'ghost start'

Additional log info available in: /home/ubuntu/.ghost/logs/ghost-cli-debug-2017-09-23T04_00_01_360Z.log

Please refer to https://docs.ghost.org/docs/v1/troubleshooting#section-cli-errors for troubleshooting.`

Comment: Did you try `sudo ghost start`

Comment: I did try that @TarunLalwani. It seems that somehow the error has resolved itself. Unfortunately I don't know how. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've experienced 502 issues with ghost behind nginx several times over a few years of running it.  I'm not sure if the cause of mine today is the same as yours, but what I observed was that after a restart ghost had changed its port number to one different than what its nginx config was listening on.

I followed these directions from https://web.archive.org/web/20200807095031/https://www.danwalker.com/running-ghost-on-a-5-digital-ocean-vps/ which resolved it for me:

See which port ghost is running on:

```
sudo netstat -plotn
```

Check that it matches the `proxy_pass` in the nginx config file in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

In my case the port in the nginx config had incremented to 2369 while the actual node process was running on 2368.  Changing the `proxy_pass` port back to 2368 in my ghost blog's nginx config file resolved the issue for me.

Comment: This is what solved the problem for me after upgrading to Ghost 2.6.0. The Nginx config had port 2368 while Ghost was running on 2369.

Comment: Same here, after upgrading to Ghost 2.18.1. Same pair of ports, even (2368, but now 2369).

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem after upgrading ghost.

Make sure the **port number** configured in your ghost's config file and the **proxy_pass** in your ghost site's nginx configuration files match.

Check the port number in 
`/var/www/ghost/config.production.json` matches the *proxy_pass* port in the nginx config files.

```
/var/www/ghost/system/files/<yourDomainName>.<extension>.conf
/var/www/ghost/system/files/<yourDomainName>.<extension>-ssl.conf
```

In my case I had to change 2368 to 2369 in the nginx config files to fix the issue.

Make sure you **restart your ghost and nginx** after you make the changes.

```sh
# restart your ghost site
cd /var/www/ghost/
ghost restart 
# restart nginx
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently when I posted this issue it was due to a bug in the Ghost CLI that the ghost team were in the process of fixing.

They provided me with these instructions to run on my server:

```
systemctl stop ghost_www-blogwebsite-com
ghost update --force
```

The resulting output:

```
stopping Ghost [skipped]
Removing old Ghost versions [skipped]
```

This fixed the problem and updated to the correct version.